# I have an issue concerning object oriented programming in java (beginner)

Tags: java

I'm trying to modify the first constructor of class animal and also the make_speak method of the given program so it will print something like :"Hello, I am a cat called Ludwig. I have eaten: ..."

The first constructor of class animal has to be modified in a way so animal object can be created by writing:

```
Animal named_cat = new Animal( "cat", "Ludwig" ) ;
```

MY QUESTION : What am I doing wrong modifying the first constructor of class animal (or other parts). thank you!

here is the program with my modifications:

```
class  Animal
{
   String  species_name ;
   String  stomach_contents ;

 \\ here I added the String animal_name

   String  animal_name;




   public Animal( String  given_species_name ) 
   {

      species_name      =  given_species_name;
      animal_name       =  given_animal_name;
      stomach_contents  =  "" ;           

   }


 public Animal( Animal  another_animal )
   {
      species_name      =  another_animal.species_name ;
      stomach_contents  =  another_animal.stomach_contents ;

   }



   public void feed( String  food_for_this_animal )
   {
      stomach_contents  =  
      stomach_contents  +  food_for_this_animal  +  ", "  ;
   }


   public void make_speak()
   {
      System.out.print( "\n Hello, I am a " + species_name     +    "called  " + animal_name + "."
                      + "\n I have eaten: " + stomach_contents + "\n" ) ;

   }


   public void make_stomach_empty( )
    {

       stomach_contents  =  "" ;

    }        

}

class  Animals
{
   public static void main( String[] not_in_use )
   {
     Animal  cat_object  =  new Animal( "cat") ; 
     Animal named_cat = new Animal( "cat", "Ludwig" ) ;
     Animal  dog_object  =  new Animal( "vegetarian dog" ) ;




      cat_object.feed( "chicken" ) ;
      cat_object.make_speak() ;
      cat_object.make_stomach_empty();

      dog_object.feed( "salad");
      dog_object.make_speak();
      dog_object.make_stomach_empty();


      Animal  another_cat  =  new Animal( cat_object ) ;

      another_cat.feed( "milk" ) ;

      cat_object.make_speak() ;
      dog_object.make_speak() ;
      another_cat.make_speak() ;

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have 2 arguments in the constructor instead of 1.

```
public Animal( String  given_species_name, String given_animal_name) {
    species_name = given_species_name;
    animal_name = given_animal_name;
    stomach_contents = "";           
}
```

But since you seem to be creating an object using the single parameter constructor as well, do not replace the provious constructor with this. Instead, add another constructor with 2 parameters.

Comment: What am I doing wrong? I wrote the same eight seconds after you ;)

Comment: @R.J Well, I actually told him to accept your answer ;) You were faster and pointed out to use a separate constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the parameter to the constructor:

```
public Animal( String  given_species_name, String given_animal_name ) {
  species_name      =  given_species_name;
  animal_name       =  given_animal_name;
  stomach_contents  =  "" ;           
}
```

Comment: @CashVai You're welcome. Please accept R.J's answer by clicking the green check mark next to his answer :)